# How to change Algolia client log level in Scala/Java?

Tags: algolia

how can I change Algolia client loglevel in Scala/Java? Right now it's set to debug and puts out a lot of garbage in the console for every search/indexing action.

Thanks.

Comment: Which API client(s) are you using exactly? Java v1, Java v2 and/or Scala?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the API client that logs and not the underlying async-http-client?

Have you tried putting

```
<logger name="com.ning.http" level="ERROR"/>
```

in your `logback.xml` file ?

Comment: Using logback.xml seems to affect the output, but I will have to check it further.